# How to add a string registry entry that contains backslashes itself?

Tags: javascript, registry

I want to add an entry in the registry at `AppCompatFlagsRegistryKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\"` by using a Jscript. However the entry that I want to add is a `REG_SZ` which has a name with backslashes itself.
For example: 
`name = "C:\Program Files\vendor\myPackage.exe"` and the `Data = "RUNASADMIN"`.
When I use: `WshShell.RegWrite( AppCompatFlagsRegistryKey + name, value, type);`

The result is that only the last part of the name (package.exe) is seen as leaf. I tried

`name = "\" + "C:\Program Files\vendor\myPackage.exe" + "\"`

but that does not help. Any suggestions what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure javascript can't temper with registry, correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: I am not running this from a browser. But as a Jscript from the command line  (addStufftoRegistry.js)

Comment: This is because RegWrite does not understand properly in final string "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\C:\Program Files\vendor\myPackage.exe" where ends KeyName and where begin new ValueName. Possible is a limitation of RegWrite

Answer (score 1):

You must escape every `\` in a literal string with `\\` to avoid js from treating `\?` as an escape sequence;

```
name = "C:\\Program Files\\vendor\\myPackage.exe";
```

**Edit:**

Doesn't seem like you can do that with `RegWrite`, here is a way with WMI:

```
var AppCompatFlagsRegistryKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers";
var name = "C:\\Program Files\\vendor\\myPackage.exe";
var Data = "RUNASADMIN";
var result;
var objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv");

try {
    result = objRegistry.SetStringValue(0x80000001 /*HKCU*/, AppCompatFlagsRegistryKey, name, Data);
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
    result = 0;
}
alert("success: " + (result == 0));
```

Comment: That is correct. My double backslashes got lost while copying pieces of code into the browser, while making this post. So in fact I am using double backslashes in all of the strings.

Comment: Updated using StdRegProv instead

Comment: Dear @Alex K. I want to do such a following batch file with your method:

`REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\com.google.chrome.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0com.google.chrome.example.echo-win.json" /f`

could you please help me?

Comment: %~dp0 is the directory containing this bat script and ends with a backslash

Comment: I want to add a registry using javascript for a page which open locally with chrome. Is it possible? I read somewhere due to security issues it is impossible. In this case what is the solution?